# Convert between SI prefixes

Tags: code-golf, parsing, conversion

### Introduction

The International System of Units is a system of measuring all around the world, except for a few countries *including the US*. The SI system (or metric system) is based on powers of ten, listed below (note that this is an incomplete table):

```
femto(f) pico(p) nano(n) micro(μ) milli(m) centi(c) (base unit) hecto(h) kilo(k) mega(M) giga(G) tera(T) peta(P)
10^-15   10^-12  10^-9   10^-6    10^-3    10^-2    10^0        10^2     10^3    10^6    10^9    10^12   10^15
```

Your job will to be to take in one of these measures and convert it into another.

### Input

Input will be a decimal number `10^-16 < x < 2^31 - 1`, an SI prefix, a letter representing a quantity, another SI prefix to convert to, and the same quantity letter. Input will be in the format `1234.56 mC to TC`, and will always match with the regex `^\d+(\.\d+)? [fpnμmchkMGTP](?'letter'[a-zA-Z]) to [fpnμmchkMGTP](?P=letter)$`. You will never have to convert to/from the base unit (`10^0`)

### Output

Output will be the same number as the input, just converted to a new SI prefix. Specifically, the program should convert the number from `SI prefix 1` to `SI prefix 2` in the input. Examples:

```
Input: 1 nm to μm
Output: 0.001

Input: 82 kC to cC
Output: 8200000

Input: 6.54 MK to hK
Output: 65400

Input: 2000 MB to GB
Output: 2
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Another thing, when generating a large/small number in this way, what should the output be? e.g. `1 PB to fB`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman you may assume the input will never produce an output that is larger/smaller than the range of digits that your language can natively handle (I think that is what you are asking).

Comment: Should we use [`U+00B5 MICRO SIGN`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/index.htm) or [`U+03BC GREEK SMALL LETTER MU`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bc/index.htm)? Can we choose either one or do we have to support one or both?

Comment: @Pietu1998 either one is fine.

Comment: Are we allowed to output a floating point number even if the result is an integer?

Comment: @Pietu1998 yes, I'll add that

Comment: In Mathematica: `({a,b,c,d}=StringSplit@#;
UnitConvert[Quantity[ToExpression@a,b],d])&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>46</s> 44 bytes

The program assumes that the character `µ` (`U+00B5 MICRO SIGN`) is used for the micro sign. On Windows, this is what you get by pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

The source code contains some unprintables, so here is a reversible `xxd` hex dump.

```
0000000: 2a76 684a 637a 645e 542d 466d 406a 4322  *vhJczd^T-Fm@jC"
0000010: 5c72 575d d623 8b9e 53bb 4c09 b275 2233  \rW].#..S.L..u"3
0000020: 3125 7443 6864 3137 2532 744a            1%tChd17%2tJ
```

Here's a copy-friendly version:

```
*vhJczd^T-Fm@j1057004749883241517573776978549 31%tChd17%2tJ
```

You can [try the demo](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*vhJczd%5ET-Fm%40jC%22%5CrW%5D%C3%96%23%C2%8B%C2%9ES%C2%BBL%09%C2%B2u%2231%25tChd17%252tJ&input=82+kC+to+cC&debug=0) or use the [test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*vhJczd%5ET-Fm%40jC%22%5CrW%5D%C3%96%23%C2%8B%C2%9ES%C2%BBL%09%C2%B2u%2231%25tChd17%252tJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1+nm+to+%C2%B5m%0A82+kC+to+cC%0A6.54+MK+to+hK%0A2000+MB+to+GB&debug=0). If these links fail, use the copy-friendly version ([demo](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*vhJczd%5ET-Fm%40j1057004749883241517573776978549%2031%25tChd17%252tJ&input=82+kC+to+cC&debug=0), [test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*vhJczd%5ET-Fm%40j1057004749883241517573776978549%2031%25tChd17%252tJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1+nm+to+%C2%B5m%0A82+kC+to+cC%0A6.54+MK+to+hK%0A2000+MB+to+GB&debug=0)).

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>113</s> 109 bytes

```js
s=>(p=s.split` `)[m={f:-9,p:-6,n:-3,µ:0,m:3,c:4,h:8,k:9,M:12,G:15,T:18,P:21},0]/(10**(m[p[3][0]]-m[p[1][0]]))
```

Edit: Apparently we can use `µ`(`U+00B5 MICRO SIGN`) for the micro sign now, so replacing with that saves a byte.

For ES6 compatibility `(10**(m[p[3][0]]-m[p[1][0]]))` can be replaced with `Math.pow(10,m[p[3][0]]-m[p[1][0]])` for 114 bytes.

### Explanation

```js
s=>                                  // s = input string
  (p=s.split` `)                     // p = input parts

    // m = dictionary of SI prefix digit powers of 10
    //     the exact values don't matter as long as they are relative to each other
    [m={f:-9,p:-6,n:-3,µ:0,m:3,c:4,h:8,k:9,M:12,G:15,T:18,P:21},

    0]                               // get the number
      /(10**(m[p[3][0]]-m[p[1][0]])) // get the factor to divide by from the difference
                                     //     between the SI prefix powers of 10
```

### Test

This test uses `Math.pow` instead of `**` so that common browsers can test it.

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="2000 MB to GB" /><button onclick="result.innerHTML=(
  
  s=>(p=s.split` `)[m={f:-9,p:-6,n:-3,µ:0,m:3,c:4,h:8,k:9,M:12,G:15,T:18,P:21},0]/Math.pow(10,m[p[3][0]]-m[p[1][0]])
  
)(input.value)">Go</button><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby (2.2.1), <s>126</s> 123 bytes

```
r={f:-9,p:-6,n:-3,µ:0,m:3,c:4,h:8,k:9,M:12,G:15,T:18,P:21};p ($*[0].to_r/10**(r[$*[3][0].to_sym]-r[$*[1][0].to_sym])).to_f
```

Saved 3 bytes thanks to user81655

### Explanation

```
# Hash of prefixes to relative powers
r={f:-9,p:-6,n:-3,µ:0,m:3,c:4,h:8,k:9,M:12,G:15,T:18,P:21};
p (                      # print (inspect)
  $*[0].to_r             # input value
  / 10 ** (              # divided by 10^...
    r[$*[3][0].to_sym]   # first prefix symbol
    -
    r[$*[1][0].to_sym]   # second prefix symbol
  )
).to_f                   # convert to float for proper format on output
```

Takes input from the command line e.g `ruby si.rb 1 nm to μm`

This is my first golf!

Comment: You can save 3 bytes if you use the values `{f:-9,p:-6,n:-3,µ:0,m:3,c:4,h:8,k:9,M:12,G:15,T:18,P:21}` for the hash table. Also replacing `μ` with `µ` (`U+00B5`) is allowed and will save another byte.

Comment: @user81655 good advice, thanks! The two mu/micro symbols seem to give the same byte count when I wc -c my file, any idea why that is?

Comment: No problem. Your file is probably encoded using something like UTF-8 which splits characters above 127 into two bytes. If you switch to a one-byte encoding like ANSI it should remove the extra byte from the file.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 143 bytes

Call `s`.

```hs
import Data.List
s=i.words
i(n:f:_:[t])=read n*10**(x f-x t)
x=j.flip elemIndex"f  p  n  µ  mc   hk  M  G  T  P".head
j(Just n)=fromIntegral n
```

Comment: I like your `"f  p  n  µ  mc   hk  M  G  T  P"` trick a lot. +1

Comment: I like this trick also. A tip: you can combine `x` and `j` with a pattern guard to: `x y|Just n<-elemIndex(y!!0)"f  p  n  µ  mc   hk  M  G  T  P"=fromIntegral n`.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 67 bytes

```
lS%:I0=dA"fpnµmchkMGTP"[-7 -4WY5 6ABEHK23]+:AAI3=c#C+=AAI1=c#C+=-#/
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=bFMlOkkwPWRBImZwbsK1bWNoa01HVFAiWy03IC00V1k1IDZBQkVISzIzXSs6QUFJMz1jI0MrPUFBSTE9YyNDKz0tIy8&input=MjAwMCBNQiB0byBHQg)

Uses `µ` (`U+00B5`) for the micro sign so make sure you use this in your input instead of the `μ` (`U+03BC`) in the question.

My first attempt at using CJam. Feel free to suggest improvements because I'm sure there are many!

### Explanation

Same method as my JavaScript answer.

```
lS%:P                    e# P = input parts separated by space
0=d                      e# get number as double
  A
  "fpnµmchkMGTP"
    [-7 -4WY5 6ABEHK23]+
      :A                 e# A = array of SI prefixes followed by their (relative) values
   AP3=c                 e# desired SI prefix
     #C+=                e# get SI value of prefix
   AAP1=c                e# current SI prefix
     #C+=-               e# subtract value of prefix
   #                     e# get power of SI prefix difference
/                        e# divide value by 10 ^ SI prefix difference
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 121 bytes

```
(e:l:i)!d|e==d=fromEnum l|0<1=i!d
b#i="f`pcnfµimlcmhqkrMuGxT{P~"!(b!!i)
g[(a,b)]=10**fromIntegral(b#1-b#7)*read a
f=g.lex
```

Defines a function `f :: String -> Double`. For example:

```
*Main> f "6.54 MK to hK"
65400.0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 113 + 8 (-p -Mutf8) = 121 bytes

```perl
%c=(f,-15,p,-12,n,-9,µ,-6,'m',-3,c,-2,h,2,k,3,M,6,G,9,T,12,P,15);/([0-9.]+) (.).*(.)./;$_=$1*10**($c{$2}-$c{$3})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDoIwGIbhq3Sooa3fD7QEIiHMTiQObsY4EIlGaRvFyXAsLsDBrLA87/L66@uZh7Bpa9GBdA6/aGBBJeYJVCDqI1CGFmRwg8EDGRoU2KPEEct7gM5llYhTSmV83komYhmrlaTil5prpVOlBG@/3Iy0JhtlCJrZng2OzVP/c364O/sO1HyGbhfI/wE)